# LinkedBlockingQueue - unbounded - put blocking?

Tags: java, multithreading

I have 2 simple questions here. I have a LinkedBlockingQueue which I create simply as

`new LinkedBlockingQueue()`

So I think this guarantees that is unbounded, is that right?
If indeed so, is it right to say that the method `put` can never block when called on this queue instance?

Answer (score 5):

The Java docs specify that a [no-arg constructor invocation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingQueue.html#LinkedBlockingQueue%28%29) will result in a capacity of `Integer.MAX_VALUE`, which is large but not actually infinite, so the queue is bounded (but for practical purposes, it might as well not be).

The [`put`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingQueue.html#put%28E%29) method will block only if space needs to become available, meaning it will block if the queue already has a number of elements equal to capacity.

Comment: So ... for `put` to block I need to already have `Integer.MAX_VALUE` in that queue, right (which practically means it can never block).

Comment: Yes, exactly, if you use the no-arg constructor.

Comment: No, it does no mean that it can never block. Only that in your particular case, if you put less than Integer.MAX_VALUE elements into this queue, then it will not block.

Comment: @Nikem, "practically" == "in practice".  If the OPs application never allows the queue to grow to a depth greater than two billion, _in practice_, then `q.put()` will never block.